# what does $opt as a variable name mean in php?

Tags: php, variables, foreach

At first I thought it was a metasyntatic variable but I couldn't find it in any of the lists?
Is it short for option or something?

I saw it in the code:

```
foreach( new ArrayIterator($this->validation_rules) as $var=>$opt)
```

Also does var have any meaning?

Comment: Those are just variable names, check the [PHP foreach documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.
> foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when
> you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an
> uninitialized variable. There are two syntaxes:

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

> The first form loops over the array given by array_expression. On each
> iteration, the value of the current element is assigned to $value and
> the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next
> iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).
>
> **The second form will additionally assign the current element's key to
> the $key variable on each iteration.**

In your example the author of that code just chose the name the variables `$var` and `$opt` in a possible attempt to use more meaningful names (and not doing a very good job).

Comment: I understand that he/she is just using variable names. Do they mean anything or are just general purpose variable names?

Comment: That depends on the values in the array being iterated. Based on the code you've posted they *probably* are trying to hint what the variable represents. Unfortunately those variable names are so vague we can't be sure. But otherwise those would not be normal or common names for those variables.